# Can a pointer ever point to itself?

Tags: c, pointers

My question is: **If a pointer variable has the same address as its value, is it really pointing to itself?**

For example -  in the following piece of code, is `a` a pointer to itself?

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
   int* a;
   int b = (int)&a;
   a = b;
   printf("address of a = %d\n", &a);
   printf("  value of a = %d\n", a);
}
```

If `a` is not a pointer to itself, then the same question poses again: *Can a pointer point to itself?*
Also, how is a self pointing pointer useful?

Comment: ppl, why the negvotes? too easy for you??

Comment: My **question** is... -- a "doubt" is something else entirely.

Comment: Even though it is legal, I wonder what the compiler actually does when it encounters something like this. Since the compiler puts in some optimization of its own, I would bet that it takes it out. But, I couldn't say for sure.

Comment: You can have a pointer to an int store its own memory location instead of storing the location of an int, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I found this question when I was trying to understand Obj C context void pointers, such as in "observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context". The pointer to itself was used to create a unique context, which I now understand because of this question and answer. Thanks.

Comment: Possible, but what the point ?

Comment: Here's a link to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532102/can-a-pointer-ever-point-to-itself

Comment: @NathanAdams Don't 2d+ arrays do this to themselves anyway? For each "level" the array is nested, you must deference that many times to get to the first real value, and along the way it returns the same address (To the first value) over and over until you get there. That at least reads like it's a pointer pointing to itself, several times over. Or... That's it's pseudo way of eliminating index iterators. I suppose it's a matter of interpretation. It sounds really useless if you were to do it yourself, though I guess it has a place somewhere.

Comment: @amdn [What you need is a pointer to your own comment.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532102/can-a-pointer-ever-point-to-itself#comment85107938_2532102)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

What you're actually doing there is **not** having the pointer point to itself. You are *using the memory space allocated for the pointer to store the location of the pointer*. A pointer to an int points to ints - never to other pointers to ints, including itself.

For example, let's say you create a pointer `a`:

```
int * a;
```

It gets its own spot in memory:

```
   4     a (5)    6
[....][00000000][....]
```

In this simple example, let's say a is at memory location '5'.

If you were to do this:

```
a = (int*)&a;
```

...the following would happen:

```
   4     a (5)    6
[....][00000005][....]
```

What's happening here is that `a` is pointing to what it thinks is an integer at location 5. This also happens to be the same memory location that `&a` is pointing to, but in the context of what `a` is pointing to, it's now pointing to the integer at location 5 - and that integer is 5.

For example both of these would work:

```
cout<<(int)a;//outputs 5
cout<<*a;//Outputs the integer at memory location 5 - which is 5.
```

If you wanted to create a pointer to a, you most definitely could - either of these ways:

```
int **b = (int**)a;
```

or

```
int ** b = &a;
```

But it's very important to realize that `a` isn't a pointer to itself. It's a pointer to the *integer at the location it stores* - which just happens to be the same as its own location.

---

To further show (through an even simpler example) what's going on, something similar could happen with an `int`. That is, you can store the memory location of an `int` within itself:

```
int a=999;
```

`a` now has a location in memory, and has a value of 999 (we'll pretend it's been placed in the memory location '46'):

```
  45     a (46)   47
[....][00000999][....]
```

It's in the location '46' - if we wanted, we could store this number as an integer within `a`:

```
a=(int)&a;

  45     a (46)   47
[....][00000046][....]
```

and now `a` is equal to `&a` in value, but *not in type* - `a` is just an integer, it doesn't point to itself magically now just because we used it to store its own memory location.

Comment: I don't understand why, in the first example, `a` doesn't point to itself, since its content is a memory addresse (definition of a pointer, isn't it?) -in this case, its own address- and not an integer (it has been casted to a `int*`).
So, obviously, `&a` and `a` produce the same result when printed, say `0xABCD`. But now, I can legally write `*a = 0x1234`, and `cout << a` shows that the **dereferenced pointer**, `a` has been modified : `&a = 0xABCD` but `a = 0x1234`.
Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @Greg82 Because by definition from `int *a;`, `a` must be pointing to an `int` but after `a=(int*)&a;` the variable `a` would be pointing to an `int *` which it should not do. (For the record, the type of `&a` is `int **`) Because pointers are treated as integers (at least usually and maybe as dictated by the C standards, I dunno), things work out but it needn't be the case in a language or architecture that treated pointers differently from integers.

Answer (score 43):

```
void* p = &p;
```

It's not terribly useful, but structs that point to themselves are useful in circular lists of length 1:

```
typedef struct A {
  struct A* next;
} A;

A a = { &a };
```

Per your exact example, I believe you meant:

```
int* a;
int b = (int)&a;
a = (int*)b;

// which can be simplified to:
int* a = (int*)&a;
```

Comment: Note that what you did with the struct is different from what he was trying to do.  A pointer that points to itself is quite different from a structure that has a pointer to itself.  +1 for the example though, as that is probably what he should be thinking of with self-referential pointers.

Comment: @Phil: It is conceptually different, which is where all the benefit comes from, but note that A::next does point to itself, as it is the first member of the struct so `&a == &a.next`.

Comment: The first example is indeed useful: it creates a unique pointer value at compile time which might be useful to mark certain objects or convey some information that is not possible otherwise in some situations (e.g., unmodifiable APIs). But for that definition of the pointer alone would be enough... assigning it just spares one from using `&` additionally :)

Answer (score 6):

Well, first I'd change the code around:

```
int **a;
a = (int **)&a;  // otherwise you get a warning, since &a is int ***
```

I'm not sure why you would do this, but it is allowed.

```
printf("The address of a is %p\n", &a);
printf("a holds the address %p\n", a);
printf("The value at %p is %p\n", a, *a); // the *a is why we made a an int **
```

They should print out the same thing.

```
The address of a is 0x7fffe211d078
a holds the address 0x7fffe211d078
The value at 0x7fffe211d078 is 0x7fffe211d078
```

Note that this is not a good idea, as that very first cast `a = (int **)&a` is a hack to force `a` to hold a value that it shouldn't hold.  You declare it an `int **` but try to force an `int ***` into it.  Technically the sizes are the same, but in general don't do that because people expect that an `int *` holds the address of something that can be used as an `int`, an so on.

Answer (score 4):

Yes and no, because the pointer's type is almost as important as the pointer's value.

Yes, a pointer can contain the position of a pointer to itself; even a long can contain the position of a pointer to itself. (Ints usually can, but I don't know if that's guaranteed everywhere.)

However, there is no type to represent this relationship. If you have a pointer which points to itself, you actually have a different type when you dereference it. So:

```
void *p = &p;
// *p is illegal, even though you probably wanted it to equal 'p'
if( *p != p ) {
    printf("Something's wrong");
}

int *i = (int*)&i;
// The following statement is still illegal
if( *i == i ) {
    printf("The universe works!");
}
```

I would say the answer is 'no', because it won't work unless you're going to abuse the type system. I think it's an indication that you're doing something wrong (though sometimes it's certainly necessary).

Answer (score 3):

Dereferencing a pointer results in a value of its *value type* (e.g. dereference an `int*` gives you an `int`, an `int*`s value type). For a variable to point to a pointer its value type would have to be `int*`, which is not the case for an `int*` as previously stated. So for a pointer to point to itself one would have to do some kind of cast in order to get it by the compiler:

```
int* a;
a = reinterpret_cast<int*>(&a);
```

To dereference `a`, then, you would have an `int` whose value happens to be the address at which `a` is located (mod truncation of the address to fit the type), but it is still an `int` and not an `int*`, which would require another cast.

A pointer to a pointer is often known as a *handle*, which is a different type (`int**`) than a pointer (`int*`). (Note that an `int**` handle has value type `int*`.)

Comment: This is a C++ answer for a C question. Otherwise interesting answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a pointer can point to itself as mentioned in the answers.

A possible use case is we can use this trick in lieu of NULL pointers. You can initialize int * p = (int *)&p, and check this later to see if the pointer is valid or not. This could have been used if say in a system where we wanted 0x0 and the entire address range to be valid addresses.

You can also use this trick in special C programs which would not crash on NULL pointer usage because you would avoid them altogether and on dereference system will not crash. It will lead to erroneous behavior but it may help debugging in certain situations.

Answer (score 1):

Just:

```
int *a = (int*)&a;
cout<<"checking: \n"<<&a<<"\n"<<a;
```

It points to itself.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to point to itself.

```
int* a;
a = &a;
```

But not have any use, at least explicitly like this.

Comment: Which brings up types. &a has the type int**, assigning that to `a` which is an int* is undefined behavior (well atleast if you try to do use the pointer.

Comment: error: cannot convert ‘int**’ to ‘int*’ in initialization