# Objective-C variable... pointing to itself?

Tags: objective-c, c, key-value-observing, void-pointers

I spotted this construct in some of Apple's example code for dealing with key-value observing. When adding an observer, you can add a context (in the form of a void* variable) that can uniquely identify the KVO call - particularly useful if you want multiple KVO calls to trigger the same action, as the single context can avoid using a bunch of chained or statements to check all the possibilities. This is the line that's used to declare the variable used for the context:

```
static void *aContext = &aContext;
```

It's basically declaring aContext to reference itself, assigning itself its own memory location - a brilliant trick that creates a unique identifier for the KVO context. Specifics aside, I'm curious what exactly this is called (self-assignment? circular pointer? something else?) and what other uses it may have besides KVO. I tried Googling different things but I couldn't come up with anything exactly like this, lacking the proper terminology. :)

I'm certainly going to be using this trick regularly, as it reduces the number of if statements necessary for KVO handling, which makes it that much more elegant.

Comment: I like this trick too (and thanks for pointing it out) but truth be told, it is not much simpler than `static char *aContext = "anything" ;`, which works the same way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532102/can-a-pointer-ever-point-to-itself

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/a/2532108/834998, this may also be useful in circular lists of length 1. Personally, I wouldn't call this an amazing trick; it's just an easy way to get a unique identifier that's valid *for the current execution of the app*, provided you create all other unique identifiers the same way.

Comment: It's self referential as @Jonathan said.A bit more discussion could be found at [cocoa dev list](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/322754-static-void-declaration-in-apple-example-code.html)

Answer (score 2):

I think this is overly complicated and confusing. When you want to have a unique context for KVO just declare it and use a pointer to it:

```
static int kMyObjectPropertyObservationContext;

...

[object addObserver:self
         forKeyPath:@"myProperty"
            options:0
            context:&kMyObjectPropertyObservationContext];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that the most accurate description would be "a self-referential pointer".