# Defining a pointer to refere to same variable name's reference?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c, pointers

In objective-c, I really cannot understand this:

`void *x = &x;`

my understanding is:

declare a generic pointer (hence type void*), the pointer variable name is x, and this pointer points to a reference to a variable (**that should be declared already- but it is not**) named x.

very confusing to me!

Comment: Please add comments as comments to the answer you want to comment on. Or also add an answer to your own question.

Comment: "that should be declared already- but it is not" - yes it is. The point of declaration comes *before* the initialiser. Once you understand that, the meaning should be clear.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16270323/694576

Answer (score 5):

To conclude whether this declaration

```
void *x = &x;
```

is valid you should take into account two important quotes from the C Standard.

the first one says where ths scope of an identifier starts (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 7 Structure, union, and enumeration tags have scope that begins just
>   after the appearance of the tag in a type specifier that declares the
>   tag. Each enumeration constant has scope that begins just after the
>   appearance of its defining enumerator in an enumerator list. **Any
>   other identifier has scope that begins just after the completion of
>   its declarator.**

The second one says whether a pointer of any type can be assigned to a pointer to void (6.3.2.3 Pointers)

> 1 A pointer to void may be converted to or from a pointer to any
>   object type. **A pointer to any object type may be converted to a
>   pointer to void** and back again; the result shall compare equal to
>   the original pointer.

So in this declaration

```
void *x = &x;
```

the scope of variabble x starts immediately before the assignment operator. Its complete type is `void *` and it can be assigned any pointer of other type. In the right hand there is expression of type `void **`. And according to the second quote it can be assigned to x because x is a pointer to void.

As result x will store the address of itself.

Comment: Thanks, the part about where the scope of the identifier begins is indeed exaclty what answers the question.

Answer (score 2):

For C and C++:

`x` gets assigned its own address. It points to itself afterwards.

Comment: That doesn't explain how you can assign the address of a variable to itself (in this case where it is a pointer, of course) on the same line you declare it :/

Comment: So it's completely up to the compiler to figure out this special case? I can't find anything relevant in the standard that would explain this case. (Then, that's far from trivial I'd say).

Answer (score 0):

Based on understanding of @alk answer:

**It is exactly as you say:**

```
int y = 10;
void* x = &y;
```

But in out case, x points to itself instead of `y`